# Materialdesign toolbar back arrow not showing in versions before Lollipop

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I have setup a custom black back arrow in the themes for the application to be shown on the toolbar as "homeasupindicator" - (I have one themes.xml file for v21 and also a general themes.xml for all lower versions). The relevant code is:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
...
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/black_back_arrow</item>
...
</style>
```

In lollipop this works fine, but in prior versions (e.g. Kitkat) no arrow appears in the toolbar (although the arrow is "still there", i.e. you can click in the location it should be to get the same behavior). What is the problem with this and how can I get my custom arrow to display in prior versions (using themes)?

Comment: does theme AppCompat need `homeAsUpIndicator` (no prefix) (as well as) `android:homeAsUpIndicator`. Not sure tbh

Comment: thanks - that solved it! (Removing android:homeasupindicator and replacing with just homeasupindicator)

Comment: no worries, moved to an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppCompat uses

`homeAsUpIndicator`

there is no need for the prefix

i.e. remove `android:`

The prefix is used for the native platform's implementation and because AppCompat comes fro mthe support library it uses another attribute (namely the same but without a prefix).